# Possibly DDoS? Thousand of Built local-host and Teardown local-host

Tags: cisco, firewall

I manage a Cisco ASA Firewall, and I'm receiving since some hours ago a flood of messages about built in/teardown local-host connections from the INTERNET interface.

I'm not sure if this is a DDoS attack. This happen twices a week and usually the source IPs are everything (Last day it started from 31.0.0.0 until 217.0.0.0). As the log does not show where the traffic goes I think they're flooding the public IP of the firewall.

Maybe the question is too abroad but how can I filter this behaviour preventing a possible DDoS attack?

[image: log]

Comment: Capture traffic and see what's what. Those are otherwise normal junk from an ASA. I don't see those on my ASA, but (a) it's "Unlimited", (b) it's only used for VPN termination.

Comment: throwing a "Show conn" let me see strange behaviour with one specific internal IP address so I'll continue investigating that.